# Proper ellipsis implemented using JS by character limit

Tags: javascript, html, css, ellipsis

Codepen Link - https://codepen.io/duk_mcloud/pen/yLjrNLb

```js
const relatedContent = () => {
  let allRelatedContents = document.querySelectorAll('.cmp-autopilot-rc')
  for (const relatedContent of allRelatedContents) {
    addEllipsis(relatedContent)
  }
}

const addEllipsis = (relatedContent) => {
  let allLinks = relatedContent.querySelectorAll('.cmp-autopilot-rc__link')
  for (const link of allLinks) {
    let ta = link
    let text = ta.getAttribute('aria-label')
    let limit = 84
    text = text.length > limit ? `${text.substring(0, (limit - 4))} ...` : text

    ta.innerHTML = text
  }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('.cmp-autopilot-rc')) {
    relatedContent()

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      relatedContent()
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.autopilot-related-content {
  background-color: #c7c2da;
}

.cmp-autopilot-rc {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.cmp-autopilot-rc__wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cmp-autopilot-rc__title {
  max-width: 10%;
  margin: 0 60px 0 0;
  color: #343741;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.15789rem;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.cmp-autopilot-rc__wrapper__links {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.cmp-autopilot-rc__link:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.cmp-autopilot-rc a {
  color: #5b3880;
}

.cmp-autopilot-rc__link {
  width: 310px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.05263rem;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="autopilot-related-content aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12">
  <div class="cmp-autopilot-rc">
    <div class="cmp-autopilot-rc__wrapper">
      <h1 class="cmp-autopilot-rc__title">ALSO OF INTEREST</h1>
      <div class="cmp-autopilot-rc__wrapper__links">
        <a class="cmp-autopilot-rc__link" href="#" aria-label="Individual and Family Health Insurance Plans">Individual and Family Health Insurance Plans</a> 
        <a class="cmp-autopilot-rc__link" href="#" aria-label="It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editor">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editor</a> 
        <a class="cmp-autopilot-rc__link" href="#" aria-label="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to implement a proper ellipsis using JS. I can't uses line-clamp here since client want a space before ellipsis dots. Below is the screenshot of my implementation using a character limit of 84.
[image]

As you can see the ellipsis on 3rd description is stretched to the end.
[image]

But 2nd decription is not strethed to the end, there are some space left to be filled.
[image]

But if I give a character limit of 95 this seems to be working fine, but 3rd description is not a ble to accomodate 95 characters in two line.
[image]

Seems like I need to make the character limit dynamic based on each desccription. Is there any way to do that or any other way to implement ellipsise dots with spaces ?